# symfony2 unit testing console output test name or number

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I am wondering if I can assign names to a unit test so that it displays as its run.  So if I have multiple tests all running the name of the one to fail can be found very quickly

So adding something like (this is not real code its put below for descriptive purposes).  Its the parts labelled 1.1 and 1.2 im looking to output in the console

```
$this->assertEquals(1, 
   $crawler->filter('h1:contains("About symblog")')->count(), 
  '1.1 Test one some description'
);


$this->assertEquals(1, 
  $crawler->filter('h2:contains("' . $blogTitle .'")')->count(), 
  '1.2 Another test'
);
```

Im not sure how to go about it. **Actual** code below

```
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/blogger/');

        // Check there are some blog entries on the page
        $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('article.blog')->count() > 0);


        // Find the first link, get the title, ensure this is loaded on the next page
        $blogLink   = $crawler->filter('article.blog h2 a')->first();
        $blogTitle  = $blogLink->text();
        $crawler    = $client->click($blogLink->link());

        // Check the h2 has the blog title in it
        $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('h2:contains("' . $blogTitle .'")')->count());

    }
```

[image: phpUnit output example]

Answer (score 3):

Just use `--debug` flag like this:

```
phpunit -c app --debug path/to/your/tests
```

Comment: that is better - it at least narrows it down to the function.  Still hoping I can go further by assign each test a name.  +1

Comment: Thanks. I assume that by "test" you really mean an assertion, right? Because "test" is whole method, so the name of test is the same as name of the method. If you want provide names or labels to your assertions you already gave an example how to do that. You just pass a third argument to eg. "assertEquals" (or second in some cases like "assertTrue") to your assertions. Or maybe I've missed your concerns?

Comment: I'm looking for it to output '1.2 Another test' or whatever I type as a string to the console as part of the assertion. Thanks to the "--debug" I now have the test function name.  The example I gave does not work it was put there to describe what I'm trying to do.